# Doesn't save form fields to database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, forms

I have simple form from what I save data to MySQL database with PHP and Jquery. It works on my local dev environment but when pushing production, it add field to db table but it doesn't save any of the input data (name, email, phone). On local everything goes ok and it saves all info. Where could be problem? Also is this safe way to save data? Am I missing some extra input field checkings?

Here is jQuery part:

```
$('.js-form').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            url: "process.php",
            success: function (response) {
                alert('form success');
            },
            error: function (response) {
               alert('form error');
            }
        });
doSomethingAfterForm();
        return false;
    });
```

And process.php

```
    <?php

include_once('connection.php');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) :
    echo "Failed to connect to database";
endif;

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) :
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) :
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
else :
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
endif;

$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$phone = mysql_real_escape_string($phone);
$ip = mysql_real_escape_string($ip);

$sql = "INSERT INTO entries (name, email, phone, ip) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$phone', '$ip')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) :
    die('Error');
endif;

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Connection.php

```
<?php
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_username = '******';
$db_pass = '*******';

$con = mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("could not connect to mysql"); 
mysqli_select_db($con, "my") or die ("no database");   


?>
```

PHP error log shows:

> PHP Warning:  mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could
>   not be established in /

Comment: are the data types for table fields same for dev and live?

Comment: Check your php info:

You'r using -> mysql_real_escape_string function.

Has your web domain both mysql and mysqli drivers?

EDIT: That said, have you checked on production if the vars have a value before putting them on the query? Tried printing the $sql after you put the vars into it?

Comment: as lix said, putted it on comment

Comment: Hmm, i see in php info that there sockets for both mysql_ and mysql_. But php error log shows: PHP Warning:  mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in..

Comment: @MixedVeg Yes, data types are same on dev and live. Database and files are exact copies of each others.

Comment: Try using something different than mysql_real_escape_string, like mysqli_real_escape_string -> http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: @MarcoMura thanks. mysqli_real_escape_string helped and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
 <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
 <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
 <input type="text" id="phn" name="phone">
 <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
</form>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#submit").click(fucntion(e){
          $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          data: { name : $("#name").val(),email: $("#email").val()
                 , phone: $("#phn").val()},
          url: "process.php",
          success: function (response) {
            alert('form success');
          },
          error: function (response) {
           alert('form error');
          }
       });
       doSomethingAfterForm();
       e.preventDefault();
     });
  });
 </script>
```

Here is your solution. Use this it will work.